# Python in conda environment same as in root environment?

Tags: python, conda

I have a conda environment `env` which had `Python 2.7.10`. I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.

I deactivated `env` to install `conda-build` in my root environment. During the install process Python was updated to 2.7.11 in the root environment.

When activating again `env` I can see that Python has been updated to 2.7.11 too.

Why? Isn't an environment supposed to have its own independent copy of Python?

Comment: what OS are you using?

Comment: @mirosval I edited the question to add it.

Comment: I'm not all that familiar with conda, but my guess would be that it symlinks the system python try `which python` while in the `env`?

Comment: @mirosval It does use the Python in my environment. I just don't understand why it has been updated along with the one in the root environment.